# Updating nodejs API on Elastic Beanstalk and AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a nodejs module which I deploy to an EC2 instance via Elastic Beanstalk.

I have an AWS Lambda that will make calls to some of the APIs in this nodejs app that updates/inserts to my Aurora RDS database.

I read from [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/) that says:

> Using Elastic Beanstalk, you can simply upload your code and Elastic
>   Beanstalk automatically handles the deployment, from capacity
>   provisioning, load balancing, auto-scaling to application health
>   monitoring.

What I am not very sure is when I deploy my nodejs app, at the moment when the nodejs app is updating/deploying, if the Lambda makes call to the API at the moment, will it get an error?

How does this part work? How does the part that says "automatically handles the deployment" work? Does it mean the Lambda will still work calling the APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which [deployment policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html) you pick. "During deployment, your application might still become unavailable to users for a few seconds. You can prevent this by configuring your environment to use [rolling deployments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html) to deploy the new version to instances in batches."